# On curvature for regular curves of arc-length

Tags: differential-geometry

Why define curvature for regular curves of arc-length as well as for only regular curves?

These notes http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Gauss.pdf takes that approach, in particular in chapter 3.

Consider the proof Corollary $3.17$ on page $23$ it refers back to theorem $3.10$ which assumes arc-length parametrisation but this is not really needed imo. Hence the whole point of defining two types of curvatures leaves me confused. Does anyone understand why this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A curve can be parametrized in infinite ways. However, parametrization with its arc-length is unique (up to the direction), so it's a “natural” parametrization. With this parametrization most formulae are very neat and symmetric. So mathematicians love it and teach it. From practical point of view, one doesn't need a less general formula.

Comment: To emphasize one point: uniqueness of the arc-length parameterization first allows one to *define* curvature in a well-defined fashion; and it next allows one to *derive* other useful formulas for curvature, for example for when a curve is given another kind of parameterization.

Comment: It hit me that curvature and torsion is invariant under reparametrisation hence the theorems can be applied for general curves aswell.